# GAMS & Python / challenge connecting these two on a Mac

Tags: python, gams-math

although I went through the GAMS Python API tutorial, I am getting the following error messages when trying to run transport.py.

Can anybody help me here? I am using Python 3.6 and GAMS 24.8. 
I guess that Python and GAMS are not properly linked on my system?!

Thanks in advance!

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/kaischaal/Dropbox/Python/GAMS.py", line 4, in <module>
    from gams import *
  File "/Users/kaischaal/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gams/__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
from .workspace import *
ImportError: dlopen(/Users/kaischaal/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gams/workspace.so, 2): Symbol not found: _PyClass_Type
 Referenced from: /Users/kaischaal/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gams/workspace.so
Expected in: flat namespace
in /Users/kaischaal/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gams/workspace.so

Process finished with exit code 1
```